# Excel VB to Replace 0 and 1 with String - However String contains 1's and 0's, Need if statement to check if length =1 then replace else skip

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, replace

The spreadsheet contains approx 400(A-QE) columns and 10k rows, which is the reason I am not just using a find and replace.  Each column represents a different diagnose. The report populates a 1 or 0 under the column header which is the diagnose description. The business wants me to replace the 1 and 0 with the diagnose text preceded with an open(0) or closed(1). The problem is when I replace a zero with "OPEN C109Malignant neoplasm of oropharynx, unspecified"or similar text, when the replace 1 case runs, it sees the 1 within the string and replaces the 1 with "OPEN CCLOSED09Malignant neoplasm of oropharynx, unspecified".

I need the REPLACE function to only REPLACE a "1" or "0" if they are the only values in the field.

Here is a sample of the code.

````
Dim ary As Variant
ary = Array(0, 1)
   For i = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
   Select Case i
   Case 0
   
Sheet1.Range("F2:F1000").Replace ary(i), "OPEN B181Chronic viral hepatitis B without delta-agent OPEN"
Sheet1.Range("G2:G1000").Replace ary(i), "OPEN B182Chronic viral hepatitis C"
Sheet1.Range("H2:H1000").Replace ary(i), "OPEN C029Malignant neoplasm of tongue, unspecified"
Sheet1.Range("I2:I1000").Replace ary(i), "OPEN C109Malignant neoplasm of oropharynx, unspecified"
Sheet1.Range("J2:J1000").Replace ary(i), "OPEN C139Malignant neoplasm of hypopharynx, unspecified"
Sheet1.Range("K2:K1000").Replace ary(i), "OPEN C159Malignant neoplasm of esophagus, unspecified"
Sheet1.Range("L2:L1000").Replace ary(i), "OPEN C161Malignant neoplasm of fundus of stomach"
Sheet1.Range("M2:M1000").Replace ary(i), "OPEN C182Malignant neoplasm of ascending colon"
Sheet1.Range("N2:N1000").Replace ary(i), "OPEN C189Malignant neoplasm of colon, unspecified"
Sheet1.Range("O2:O1000").Replace ary(i), "OPEN C19Malignant neoplasm of rectosigmoid junction"
Sheet1.Range("P2:P1000").Replace ary(i), "OPEN C20Malignant neoplasm of rectum"
Sheet1.Range("Q2:Q1000").Replace ary(i), "OPEN C220Liver cell carcinoma"
Sheet1.Range("R2:R1000").Replace ary(i), "OPEN C23Malignant neoplasm of gallbladder"
Case 1
Sheet1.Range("F2:F1000").Replace ary(i), "CLOSED B181Chronic viral hepatitis B without delta-agent"
Sheet1.Range("G2:G1000").Replace ary(i), "CLOSED B182Chronic viral hepatitis C"
Sheet1.Range("H2:H1000").Replace ary(i), "CLOSED C029Malignant neoplasm of tongue, unspecified"
Sheet1.Range("I2:I1000").Replace ary(i), "CLOSED C109Malignant neoplasm of oropharynx, unspecified"
Sheet1.Range("J2:J1000").Replace ary(i), "CLOSED C139Malignant neoplasm of hypopharynx, unspecified"
Sheet1.Range("K2:K1000").Replace ary(i), "CLOSED C159Malignant neoplasm of esophagus, unspecified"
Sheet1.Range("L2:L1000").Replace ary(i), "CLOSED C161Malignant neoplasm of fundus of stomach"
Sheet1.Range("M2:M1000").Replace ary(i), "CLOSED C182Malignant neoplasm of ascending colon"
Sheet1.Range("N2:N1000").Replace ary(i), "CLOSED C189Malignant neoplasm of colon, unspecified"
Sheet1.Range("O2:O1000").Replace ary(i), "CLOSED C19Malignant neoplasm of rectosigmoid junction"
Sheet1.Range("P2:P1000").Replace ary(i), "CLOSED C20Malignant neoplasm of rectum"
Sheet1.Range("Q2:Q1000").Replace ary(i), "CLOSED C220Liver cell carcinoma"
Sheet1.Range("R2:R1000").Replace ary(i), "CLOSED C23Malignant neoplasm of gallbladder"
End Select
Next
End Sub```
````

Answer (score 0):

[`Range.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace) has a `LookAt` parameter.

Add

```vb
, xlWhole
```

to each of your `Replace` calls.